# How do I make an array of SystemSoundID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I cannot seem to figure it out.

I can play one sound with:

```
- (void) initSounds {
    // Get the main bundle for the app
    CFBundleRef mainBundle;
    mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();
    // Get the URL to the sound file to play
    soundFileURLRef  =  CFBundleCopyResourceURL (mainBundle,CFSTR ("1"),CFSTR ("wav"),NULL);

    // Create a system sound object representing the sound file
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);
}

-(void) play {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(self.soundFileObject);
}
```

But I want to create an array of SystemSoundID objects.  When I try to do this I keep getting errors.  Can anyone show me the code to create an array of soundFileObjects and how I use that array in AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Comment: I posted an alternative answer using objects [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26701297/951349

Answer (score 7):

`SystemSoundID` is an integral, non-class, type, so you'd need to use a wrapper like [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store it in Cocoa containers like `NSArray`:

```
// assuming this property:
@property (copy) NSArray *soundFileObjects;

// creating the array:
soundFileObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                     [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:soundId],
                     // more ?
                     nil];

// using it, e.g.:
SystemSoundID sid = [[self.soundFileObjects objectAtIndex:0] unsignedLongValue];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sid);
```